# Use an existing key by another one in app.config

Tags: c#, web-config, app-config

I want to know if there is a way to use a key in the value of another one.
For example i have the following config:

```
<appSettings>   
<add key="CustomerAdress" value="http://localhost/SD/Service/CustomerS.svc/ComputeCust"/>
</appSetting>
```

I want to create a key that contains the first part of the uri : http://localhost/SD/Servic

```
<add key="SdServices" value="http://localhost/SD/Service"/>
```

and use the key "SdServices" as follows :

```
<add key="CustomerAdress" value="SdServices/CustomerS.svc/ComputeCust"/>
```

Thank you.

Comment: I believe something is missing :P

Comment: Yes :P now it's fixed !!

Answer (score 0):

You can't refer to other configuration values in the configuration. While depending on your goal different approaches may be valid, the easiest would be to do the concatenation in code:

```
string customerServiceEndpoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SdServices"] 
                               + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CustomerAddress"]
```

Of course with proper error handling in place to detect missing configuration values.